# How to get product discount amount

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to get discount price of product. Check below screenshot for more info.

https://prnt.sc/oogqzp

I would like to get red marked value.

```
$items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
   $productSku = $item->getSku();
   echo $item->getBaseDiscountAmount();
   echo $item->getDiscountAmount();

}
```

Both returns null Any idea what's missing here ?

Comment: Do you get the Orders correctly? I mean do you get value for other methods of order such as tax, qty, ... from sales_order and sales_order_item tables?

Comment: Thanks for responsing, Issue was internally produced now its resolved :)